# Appending multiple tr elements dynamically with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have server generated html:

```
<div id="invContent">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

and this ajax call:

```
& .ajax({
    url: path,
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#tableID>tbody").append($(result).find("#invContent").html());
    }
});
```

The problem is tr and td tags are not being appended, only content of td's.

How can I append these multiple tr's?

Comment: try `$("#tableID>tbody").append("<tr>¬ + $(result).find("#invContent").html() + "</tr>");`

Comment: @undefined Nothing wrong with the markup?

Comment: @BillyMathews `tbody` without a `table`?

Comment: @undefined I stand corrected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this one!

I just wrapped tr's in table tag:

```
<div id="invContent">

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table
</div>
```

and `success` callback is:

```
$("#tableID>tbody").append($(result).find("#invContent>table>tbody").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is selecting and then appending the `tbody` element, which is probably generating content that is confusing to the browser (multiple `tbody` elements inside one `table`).

Try changing your `success` callback to:

`$("#tableID>tbody").append($(result).find("#invContent>tbody").html());`

An even better solution would be to update your server-side code to just return the `tr` elements so that you don't have to do any selecting/navigating in the response.